# what is the best way to create a comment model for my rails social app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a user model using devise as its authentication, a post model and are both associated with belongs_to and has_many. I want to include a third model which allows users to comment on posts.
  Is it best to create this with act_as_commentable gem or should i create this from scratch using rails version 4.2?